# Android 5.0 notification only plays audio notification once

Tags: android, audio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I have a notification in my app and I need to play a notification audio with every new (updated) notification. On Android before 5.0 it's working, but Lollipop plays the audio only once. If I make a phone call, afterwards audio notification is played, but once only again (vibration worked always).

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext()); 
builder.setSmallIcon(iconSmall).setTicker("AppName ticker" + currentTime).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
builder.setContentTitle("contentTitle");
builder.setSound(soundURI);
long[] patternr = {100, 100};
builder.setVibrate(patternr);
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
notification.category = Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM;
mNotifyMgr.notify(NOTIFI_ID, notification);
```

And I tried using:

```
notification.sound = soundUri;
```

It did not help.